# How do you extract a specific field from a JSON array in Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I currently have a JSON array that looks like this in Big Query:

```
[{"name":"","username":null},{"name":"Jimmy Dean","username":"iamjc"},{"name":"Ben Simmons","username":"bens"}]
```

I want to create a column that just has a list of username values. For the example above, I would like the column to display

```
"iamjc", "bens"
```

I've tried using json_extract_scalar with unnest but it is throwing an error because of the null value.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json2array(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return JSON.parse(json).map(x=>JSON.stringify(x));
""";
select
g.created_at as message_sent,
username as sender,
members as original_members,
ARRAY(SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.username')
  FROM UNNEST(json2array(JSON_EXTRACT(members, '$'))) x
  ) AS members
from `table_1` g
join `table_2` u
 on u._id = json_value(g.user, "$.id") and is_staff is false
where g.type = 'message.new'
order by 1 desc
```

The error on output is this:

```
Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field members
```

Would anyone know how to get this desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `WHERE` clause as in below example

```
  ARRAY(SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.username')
  FROM UNNEST(json2array(JSON_EXTRACT(members, '$'))) x
  WHERE NOT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.username') IS NULL
  ) AS members
```

Or, use below option (in which case you don't even need `json2array` UDF

```
  array(select json_extract_scalar(x, '$.username')
  from unnest(json_extract_array(members)) x
  where not json_extract_scalar(x, '$.username')is null
  ) as members
```

if applied to dummy data as in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select '[{"name":"","username":null},{"name":"Jimmy Dean","username":"iamjc"},{"name":"Ben Simmons","username":"bens"}]' members
)
select *,
  array(select json_extract_scalar(x, '$.username')
  from unnest(json_extract_array(members)) x
  where not json_extract_scalar(x, '$.username')is null
  ) as members
from your_table
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Neither works as expected

Comment: this answer suppose to address error `Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field members`. and actually if applied to sample data in y our question returns exactly what is expected!!!

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `IGNORE NULLS` when you create an array would be helpful. Refer to below query.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT '[{"name":"","username":null},{"name":"Jimmy Dean","username":"iamjc"},{"name":"Ben Simmons","username":"bens"}]' AS members
)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(JSON_VALUE(m, '$.username') IGNORE NULLS) AS members 
  FROM sample_data, UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(members, '$')) m;

+------+---------+
| Row  | members |
+------+---------+
| 1    | iamjc   |
|      | benj    |
+------+---------+
```

And since `JSON_EXTRACT_*` functions became a legacy, better use new JSON functions:

- `JSON_VALUE*`
- `JSON_QUERY*`
- https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/spring-forward-bigquery-user-friendly-sql